# How can I add lastlog support to Alpine Linux?

Tags: logs, syslog, alpine-linux

Apparently, [musl, the default library for Alpine Linux](https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org/alpine/aports/issues/5075) does not support `lastlog`. Generally you will use Alpine to deploy containers that do not need that kind of support, but it could be used also to give lightweight virtual machine support to users, with pedagogic purposes, for instance. Is there any package that emulates lastlog, or is there a way to process syslog to generate lastlog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the best approach is one suggested by Lorenzo Beretta for Void Linux on 2019-10-10: make the applications in question dynamically link to Laurent Bercot's `utmps` library in place of the musl C library, using `LD_PRELOAD`.

## Further reading

- Laurent Bercot (2017). *[utmps — a secure utmp implementation](http://skarnet.org/software/utmps/)*. skarnet.org.

Comment: `utmps` doesn't support lastlog. `utmps` only support utmp, wtmp and btmp file. `lastlog` is not coverd by `utmps`.